# Doors No. 1 and 2 or Door Nos. 1 and 2?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

If there are three doors in a building numbered No.1, No.2, and No.3.  When referring to them collectively, do I say "**Doors No. 1, 2, and 3**"; or "**Door Nos. 1, 2, and 3**"?

Comment: Some contexts will call for "door no. 1 and door no. 2."

Answer (score 8):

It primarily depends whether you're referring to the ***doors*** or the ***numbers** [the "signage"]*. Thus...

> 1: ***Doors number** 1 and 2 are open, but that door number 3 is closed*
> 2: ***Door numbers** 1 and 2 are visible, but I can't see the number on that door*

In some contexts, the door ***number*** effectively *represents* the door it's on, so it doesn't really make any difference which you pluralize...

> 3: *I searched the corridor, but couldn't find **doors number** 1 and 2*
> 4: *I searched the corridor, but couldn't find **door numbers** 1 and 2*

---

But it's worth pointing out that *syntactically*, I have no problem at all with [this sentence](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22while%20doors%20numbers%22) pulled out by Google Books...

> 5: *Door number 113 is located in Room 102 while **doors numbers** A03 and A04 are located in the Ash Silo Enclosure*

Comment: I'd be quite happy with just 'doors 1 and 2 are open, and 3 is closed'.

Comment: So would I. But that doesn't imply there's anything *wrong* with including the word "number" - whether pluralised or not.